# How to run Vim shell from script's path?

Tags: python, vim

*Search results returned tones of Q&As and I don't know how to rephrase this better, so pardon me if it's a duplicate:*

I'm running a python script with Vim. The script is at `~/path/to/my/script.py` and there is a style sheet file in the same path.

The code's content opens the file:

```
f = open('./stylesheet.css', 'r')
s = f.read()
f.close()
```

And if I run my code from Vim like so `:!python %`,it will return: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'stylesheet.css'`

So it seems Vim runs my code not from the code's location, but from /home or root?

How can I make it use the code's path as the root path during execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this `:lcd %:p:h | !python %`.

A brief explanation. lcd changes directory to the current file being edited - http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file

Then executes the python command on the file.

The one problem with this command is that your current directory will now be (from your example) `~/path/to/my/`. You will have to do another `:lcd` to get back to your current directory. I wasn't able to find a way to combine all of it into one command in vim. Maybe someone else can.

**Edit - How-to cd back again**

(*removed my complex method*)

for the simple solution refer to ib's comments below.

Comment: Great thanks. I will map this into a new command `:runthere` or something like this.

Comment: User-defined commands have to start with uppercase I think. Have a look at the edited answer. You can change the :CDP to :Runthere or something. Cheers, this was an interesting exercise in getting to know vim a little better.

Comment: Why implement this so overcomplicated?  Just use something like `:lcd %:p:h | exe'!python '.expand('%') | lcd -`.  By the way, it is probably useful to use `sil lcd` instead of just `lcd` to suppress reporting of the current working directory path on each change.

Comment: @ib - Thanks! I knew there was a simpler way, I just couldn't chain the 2nd lcd command. It was getting clubbed into the 2nd command which I was trying with :!python %.

Answer (score 1):

To open a file in the same directory as your script, try something like:

```
import os

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
target_file = os.path.join(script_dir, 'stylesheet.css')

with open(target_file, 'r') as f:
  s = f.read()
```

Comment: I don't take it as a solution because it was Vim-specific and so was the answer I chose. But I like what you provided and will definitely use it as a safety belt :)

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut in vim for the current file is %, so instead of `:!python $`, type `:!python %`

Comment: sorry it was a typo from my part :(, I meant %

Comment: Okay, your vim instance might have an incorrect current working directory, type `:!pwd`, is it the directory that contains `stylesheet.css`?

Comment: @habitmelon You don't need `!`: `:pwd` will also print current working directory.

Comment: @habitmelon: Nope, `:pwd` returns `/home/benjamin` my code and css both are at `/home/benjamin/programming/myproject/src/`

Comment: Then type `:cd /home/benjamin/programming/myproject/src/`, and then the original command you tried should work.